# Pass Variable to Chrome Popup Extension

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a chrome extension that has a content script that should, scrape an id from the active page and, pass it via chrome.runtime.sendMessage to popup.js

Unfortunately I can't seem to understand why I can't pass is as a global variable between the functions.

I've created an example fiddle here of what I'm trying to do -

```
  function getCID(){
  var cid = $('.qx-h').text();
  var cid = cid.replace(/\D/g,'');
  return cid
}

chrome.runtime.sendMessage(cid());

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message) {
    document.getElementById('pagetitle').innerHTML = message;
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/dqkz9yt3/

I suppose I need a callback function to resolve the issue? I can however get chrome.runtime.sendMessage to work when I'm just using something without a function like document.title

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage(document.title);

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (message) {
    document.getElementById('pagetitle').innerHTML = message;
});
```

If someone can point me in the direction of the theory to understand why I'm stuck, I'd be grateful.

Thanks,

Dan

Comment: Now don't tell me you were trying chrome extension on jsfiddle.

Comment: fortunately not - it's an unpacked extension - but I didn't think anyone would like to see that? - it's more just a fiddle to show the logic.